# Person Account Custom Field

Tags: custom-field, contact, person-accounts

I have added a custom field called 'National ID' on the Contact Object. The field appears on the page layout for both objects in SetUP, but when I go to the Person Account detail page in the User Interface, I cant find the field. How do i resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be some possible reasons why this is happening, such as:

- The custom field is not added to the page layout for the Person Account record type.

  - In Setup, go to Object Manager and select Account.
  - Click Page Layouts in the sidebar, and then click the name of the page layout that is assigned to the Person Account record type.
  - In the page layout editor, drag the National ID field from the Fields section to the location where you want it to appear on the page layout.
  - Click Save.
- The custom field is not visible or editable for the profile or permission set that you are using.

  - In Setup, go to Object Manager and select Contact.
  - Click Fields & Relationships in the sidebar, and then click the National ID field name.
  - Click Set Field-Level Security in the Field Details section.
  - Select the checkbox for the profile or permission set that you want to grant access to the field, and choose the level of access, such as Visible or Read-Only.
  - Click Save.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385368&type=1

Comment: Thank you Tushar Jadav. The first solution worked.